# How to find the file name for files generated by pdf2image

Tags: python

I am trying to convert my `pdf` files to `jpg`. I first use pdf2image to save the file as a `.ppm`. Then I want to use PIL to convert the `.ppm` to `.jpg`.

How do I find the name of the file that pdf2image saved?

Here is my code:

```
def to_jpg(just_ids):
    for just_id in just_ids:
        image = convert_from_path('/Users/davidtannenbaum/Desktop/scraped/{}.pdf'.format(just_id), output_folder='/Users/davidtannenbaum/Desktop/scraped/')
        file_name = ?
        im = Image.open("/Users/davidtannenbaum/Desktop/scraped/{}.ppm".format(file_name))
        im.save("/Users/davidtannenbaum/Desktop/scraped/{}.jpg".format(just_id))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to, the `image` variable should contain a list of `Image` objects. You can simply do:

```
for i, im in enumerate(image):
    im.save("/Users/davidtannenbaum/Desktop/scraped/{}_{}.jpg".format(just_id, i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `convert_to_path()` method has a few more parameters you can use. You can set the `paths_only` parameter to `True` and the format attribute `fmt` to `"jpeg"`.

This will directly save your images to your output folder in JPG format instead of PPM and the `image` variable will contain the relative paths to each image instead of the image objects.

```
for just_id in just_ids:
        image = convert_from_path('/Users/davidtannenbaum/Desktop/scraped/{}.pdf'.format(just_id), output_folder='/Users/davidtannenbaum/Desktop/scraped/', fmt="jpeg", paths_only=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pdf_path = '/path/to/pdf_images/'
output_folder = '/path/for/output/images/'

for pdf in os.listdir(pdf_path):
    filename = pdf.split('.')[0] # prepare your filename 
    pdfs = convert_from_path(os.path.join(pdf_path,pdf),output_folder=output_folder, output_file=os.path.join(output_folder+ filename), fmt="jpeg")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).